# Best practices for CPT without using an editor

Tags: block-editor

I would really appreciate your help here.
I am building a simple podcast plugin to add podcast episodes to the site. I have two CPT's for this 'podcast' for episodes and 'guest'.

The quest will not have an archive and single templates enabled. It will be only for storing Guest information and displaying it on the episode (podcast CPT) pages using custom block.

I think there are a couple of ways I could work on this but I need some help.

Option 1 - would be to use old way and create a custom metabox for all settings and content for the guest.

Option 2 - Use Gutenberg where all options are in the CPT plugin sidebar. I was also thinking I could create a custom block for preview when editing guests. I would need to hide all other blocks for that CPT and use templates to display preview block only not allowing to delete the block or add another.

Option 3 - any other way I should approach this problem?

custom meta needed for this CPT (name, description, email, social links, custom links)

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  As a Q&A reference site (not a discussion forum) questions like this are considered out of scope. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the custom block option quite extensively. I enable the editor for the custom post type, but use a custom template with `template_lock` set to `true`:

```php
'template' => array(
    array('pb/custom-block-name'),
),
'template_lock' => true
```

Then I use the `allowed_block_types_all` filter to only allow that custom block for the post type:

```php
function pb_allowed_block_types($allowed_block_types, $block_editor_context) {
    if (!$block_editor_context->post || $block_editor_context->post->post_type !== 'custom_post_type') {
        return $allowed_block_types;
    }

    return array(
        'pb/custom-block-name',
    );
}
add_filter('allowed_block_types_all', 'pb_allowed_block_types', 10, 2);
```

Finally, I use custom post meta within the custom block using `useEntityProp` to get and set the meta:

```js
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
import { useEntityProp } from '@wordpress/core-data';

const Edit = (props) => {
    const postType = useSelect((select) => (
        select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType()
    ));

    const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp('postType', postType, 'meta');

    return (
        <TextControl
            label={ __('Label', 'pb') }
            value={ meta._pb_meta_slug }
            onChange={ (value) => setMeta({_pb_meta_slug: value}) }
        />
    );
};
```

Make sure you use `register_post_meta` to register all your post meta for the custom post type or it won't save:

```php
register_post_meta('custom_post_type', '_pb_meta_slug', array(
    'type' => 'string',
    'single' => true,
    'auth_callback' => function() {
        return current_user_can('edit_posts');
    },
    'show_in_rest' => true,
));
```

Comment: Fantastic @Phil, thank you. That was exactly what I wanted to do but I was not sure if that is the best solution. I will go this route, thank you.