# WordPress Gutenberg Theme: Structure, Hierarchy and Custom Templates

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I'm starting to develop a WordPress theme using Gutenberg. I've never worked with Gutenberg before, but since the support for Classic Editor might possibly end next year, I want to use it now since I don't want to rebuild the same site for the client again next year. I'm using [Sage](https://roots.io/sage/) 10.

I've got the idea of how to build blocks (with ACF Pro or natively), but what confuses me is the theme structure/template hierarchy.

I've read all the documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/.

But the structure with folders *block-templates* and *block-template-parts* is very confusing to me. There's no PHP and only HTML files. I don't see any files from the classic [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Basically, what I want to achieve is this: create templates for posts, CPT, and custom templates. I don't want the user to edit the blocks' order, I just want them to edit the content, nothing more. I want the content editor to choose a Template and then the blocks of that template are shown and he can edit them, just like the classic way.

I saw that you can do something like [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/#locking) where you can register a template and lock the blocks list, but I can't find a similar way for custom templates.

So, my questions are these:

1. Is there a way to build a custom template with registered blocks and lock them, so when the editor chooses that template, he can only edit the block's content? What is the recommended way?
2. Is there a template hierarchy in Gutenberg themes? What are *block-templates* and *block-templates-parts*?

Comment: You would still create templates the way you did in the past - at present the Gutenberg blocks are being exclusively loaded into `the_content()`. (Well, now also in Widgets.)  I have never seen blocks being locked into templates and while I'm sure it's possible, I don't imagine it would be a simple process. (I may be wrong.)  Block Templates and Block Template parts are just segmentations the way that templates and template parts are.  For example, let's say you use a Block Template part in more than one Block Template, instead of duplicating the code, you'd just reference the template part.

Answer (score 0):

There are technically two ways to build themes now. One is the *old* standard way, where you have PHP templates (that follow the traditional template hierarchy). The other is [*block based* themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/block-theme-overview/) that use blocks for *everything*.

My recommendation is to stick with traditional for now. Full Site Editing, which is part of the block based theme work is still in its infancy and you can still use the Gutenberg editor with the *old* template method. I do this exclusively in my work.

What I typically do is include a `blocks` folder inside my theme that in turn has my `package.json` file. This is where I put all my Gutenberg specific theme stuff. So I'll have a sub folder (in `blocks/src/`) for `blocks`, `plugins`, `block-styles`, etc. I'll then add all the necessary JS to make all those blocks and plugins. Then, for templating, I use the standard `.php` template files (e.g. `archive-post_type.php`, `single.php`, etc.).

When registering a custom post type, you can specify a default "template" of blocks:

```php
register_post_type('post_type_slug', array(
    // ...
    'show_in_rest' => true, // Make sure to include this so it loads the Gutenberg editor
    'template' => array(
        array('core/heading', array(
            'level' => 2)
        ),
        array('core/paragraph'),
    ),
));
```

You can also lock the templates if you want. See [`template_lock`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) for your options.

I've written some other answers on SO for things like [how to get and set custom post meta using Gutenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176124/wordpress-gutenberg-subscribe-not-getting-updated-meta-field-value/67215125#answer-67215125), and [general best practices I use when working with custom post types in Gutenberg](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392884/best-practices-for-cpt-without-using-an-editor/392887#answer-392887). I'd suggesting checking those out as well.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer, and yes, I really like this way of adding blocks on an array for a template. My question though is: what about the case of custom templates? I want the user to create a page, choose a template, and then these chosen blocks by me are shown. Is there a similar way like CPT but for custom templates? How is your solution to this problem?

Comment: I haven't done anything quite like that in my own work, but you could use `useSelect` to get the template (`const template = useSelect((select) => select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('template'));`) then `createBlock` to insert whatever blocks you want (`useDispatch('core/block-editor').insertBlocks(createBlock('core/heading'));`). The one thing you'll want to consider is what to do with _existing_ content if the user changes templates.